# tanimoto coefficient in the book of Programming Collective Intelligence

Tags: data-mining

I have read the book of Programming Collective Intelligence. For the after-class exercise 1 of chapter 2, could someone please tell me how to calculate the **tanimoto coefficient**? A specific mathematical formula will be really appreciated.

Comment: Yes, i used Google, but i'm not sure which is the right one as referred in the book:(

Comment: Have found the answer on this site https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-collective-intelligence/9780596529321/apbs04.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extensive search on a related question has given me two formulas:

1. T(a,b) = N_intersection  / (N_a + N_b - N_intersection) found [here](http://mines.humanoriented.com/classes/2010/fall/csci568/portfolio_exports/sphilip/tani.html), which is the same as on Wikipedia in a slightly more readable fashion.
   EDIT: As per your comment, this is the one the OP was looking for.
2. (n_11+n_00) / [n_11+2(n_10+n_01)+n_00], where

   - n_11: both have attribute,
   - n_00: both don't have attribute,
   - n_01 or n_10: only second/first object has the attribute.

For the source of the second equation have a look at http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RogersTanimotoDissimilarity.html and calculate the similarity index from the dissimilarity index as (1-dissimilarity).

I believe that the second formula is commonly used in applied statistics and applied marketing.

Comment: Thanks Joha. The formula used in the book is "1". Appreciated for your extension.